# Remover espaços de entrada de texto

Tags: php, wordpress

meu tema tem o seguinte código:

```
$section_content .= '<span class="topbar-phone"><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55'. esc_attr( ekko_get_option( 'tek-business-phone' ) ) .'" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i><span>'. esc_html( ekko_get_option( 'tek-business-phone' ) ) .'</span></a></span>';
```

ele me retorna um link do whatsapp:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55 + o que a pessoa digitou no painel como sendo o telefone. Só que se a pessoa digitar o telefone com espaços, o link do Whatsapp Web vai vir com espaços...

Ex: se a pessoa digitar o telefone 21 99999-9999

o código vai retornar:https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5521 99999-9999

e eu queria que retornasse 5521999999999

Como eu faço para o php já remover esses espaços na saída

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar um preg_replace para pegar apenas os números

Exemplo:

```
preg_replace('/\D/g', '', $suastring)
```